# How to enable/disable a submit button in a Webix window with proper validation message?

Tags: webix

I have a popup window which has a 'name' text field and a 'Submit' button.
I want the 'Submit' button to remain disabled until the 'name' field has some value and also show a message in the window that 'name field can not be empty to submit'.

I have made the button disable work.
However, not able to show the message and enable the 'Submit' button once the name field has value.

My snippet is here : https://webix.com/snippet/3194cb53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below Jsfiddle link and please let me know in case you still face any issue. Please also let me know where you want to show the message (i think there is no need of msg because you are already disabling the submit button) :

https://webix.com/snippet/05ba29f2

Please find the link after adding the validation_message :
https://webix.com/snippet/29319913

Comment: It is working no doubt. But suppose I have constraint that the provided name can not be a particular string (for example 'name'). In that case apart from disabling the button I also want to show that 'name' can not be a valid name for this 'name' field. Hope I could explain the problem.

Comment: please look into the latest link

Comment: Thanks it is working. However, I was thinking of if the same thing could have been done using 'rules'  https://docs.webix.com/api__link__ui.form_validate.html  . Just a thought.

Comment: You can also do by using rules, but it will only be displaying the error msgs on top right. I think it's better to show the validation messages just above the controls.